# Jquery ajax POST label/value pair

Tags: php, jquery

I want to pass label/value pair in Ajax .POST but cannot find any solution. Ajax .POST normally send id/value pair but I cannot change my id and would like to send labels/value pair instead. I have provided partial form. Any help please.

```
        $.ajax({
            url:"allfields.php",
            type:"POST",
    //      dataType:"json",
            data: $("#frmRequest").serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                alert("Form Submitted: "+ msg);
                return msg;

              },
             error: function() {
            alert('Error occured');
             }
        });

<body>
     <form id="frmRequest" name="frmRequest" >

                <div class="clearfix" id="idRequestDetails"  >
                    <table width="809" border="0" id="tbl_data_1_1_1_1__" summary="Profile">
                      <tr>
                        <th width="156" scope="col"><label class="labelrequest" for="txtProfileName1__">Name</label>
                        </th>
                        <th width="74" scope="col"><label class="labelrequest" for="txtProfileUserID1__">User ID</label></th>
                        <th width="131" scope="col"><label class="labelrequest" for="txtSiteCost1__">Site Cost Centre</label></th>
                         <th width="182" scope="col"><label class="labelrequest" for="txtDetail1__">Additional Details</label></th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtProfileName1__" id="txtProfileName1__" tabindex="100" /></td>
                        <td><input name="txtProfileUserID1__" type="text" class="clearfix" id="txtProfileUserID1__" tabindex="110" size="8" /></td>
                        <td><input name="txtSiteCost1__" type="text" id="txtSiteCost1__" tabindex="220" size="8" /></td>

                        <td><textarea name="txtDetail1__" rows="1" id="txtDetail1__" tabindex="240"></textarea></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem some more than just saying "It doesn't work".

Comment: added form, any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example:

***HTML***

```
<form>
    <label>Label1</label><input type="text" value="1">
    <label>Label2</label><input type="text" value="some">
</form>
```

***jQuery***

```
var dataToServer = [];
$('form label').each(function() {
    dataToServer.push({
        label: $(this).text(),
        value: $(this).next().val()        
    });
});

console.log(data);
// output
// [ {label: 'Label1', value: '1'}, {label: 'Label2', value: 'some'}]
```

***[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/WmQvT/1/)***.

Hope this can give you some guideline.

#### According to commnet

***AJAX part***

```
$.ajax({
    url: "allfields.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data: dataToServer,   // send above data here
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("Form Submitted: " + msg);
        return msg;
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error occured');
    }
});
```

#### Final shot

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var dataToServer = [];
    $('#frmRequest label').each(function(i, el) {
        var temp= {},
            label = $(this).text(),
            value = $('#' + $(this).attr('for')).val();
        temp[label] = value;
        dataToServer.push(temp);
    });
    console.log(dataToServer);
});
```

***[See the console output](http://jsfiddle.net/DqCbz/8/)***

Comment: What do I need to do in Ajax .POST function ?

Comment: Write a function that works like this example, and returns the `data` array. Then use that instead of `.serialize`.

Comment: 1. Should I submit button be a submit button or just a button. ? & do I need to put action="url" and method="POST" in the form ?

Comment: Hi, thecodeparadox, I am running into strife. I am not not clear if your solution is with Ajax or standard form submission. Could you please edit your reply. with snippet of the solution. Sorry I am not expert in Jquery :(

Comment: Tried that:$.ajax({
 type:'POST',
         url:'allfields.php',
 data:$('#frmRequest').data,
 success: function(data){
 alert("Ok done");
 }
 }); //end of ajax

Comment: I am really struggling to code you example, please a code with Ajax part would be helpful, I am not very good at Jquery.

Comment: Based on my form I wrote $('#frmRequest label').each(function() {.... is that incorrect as I am getting 'Error occured' ???

Comment: @aus_fas I've made another example fiddle for you. Check that fiddle (with firebug/ such debuger console).

Comment: There is something wrong as there is noting in the dataToServer, write alert(dataToServer) it comes with [object Object], [object Object]....   Although I am using jquery 1.8 but can it be due to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11665

Comment: @aus_fas as `dataToServer` is object and an alert can't display object. You can see through console. But if display in alert message try `alert( JSON.stringify(dataToServer) )`.

Comment: @thecodeparadox - I'm not sure if you'll see this since it's so late, but what does (i, el) refer to in function?  I don't see the tie-in.

Comment: @Michele `i = index` and `el = element`, so instead of `this`, you can use `el` also within `.each()` callback. For further info, you can see documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/