# How post form from html to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I'm trying to POST the form from Checkbox.html to table.php.  I need the whole checkbox form in table.php so I can get what I need (labels) from what will be a really long checkBox list. I have a method that I know will parse just the labels out of an entire form.

When I run this, I start in table.php then press a button and it goes to checkbox.html.  I check some boxes and press the submit button and it's supposed to send the form back to table.php.

This is checkbox3.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- -->
<html>

    <head>
        <title>jQuery Michele Project</title>
        <link href="css/skins/polaris/polaris.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/skins/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/demo/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="js/icheck.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.input').iCheck({
                    checkboxClass:'icheckbox_polaris',
                    radioClass:'iradio_polaris',
                    increaseArea:'10%'
                });
            });
        </script>

//***The next 2 script sections are the new AJAX part. I'm not seeing alerts anymore*****
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#submit').on('click', function() {
                var serialized = $('input:checkbox').map(function() {
                    return {id: this.id, value: this.checked ? this.id : "false"};
                });
                console.log(serialized);
                alert(JSON.stringify(serialized));
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "tableReduced.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"json",
                data: serialized,   // send above data here
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert("Form Submitted: " + msg);
                        return msg;
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error occured');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>            
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myCheckboxForm" name="myCheckboxForm" action="tableReduced.php" method="POST">
    <div class="skin skin-line">
        <div class="arrows">
          <div class="top" data-to="skin-flat"></div>
          <div class="bottom" data-to="skin-polaris"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="skin skin-polaris">
        <div class="arrows">
          <div class="top" data-to="skin-line"></div>
          <div class="bottom" data-to="skin-futurico"></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Select Items for Column Headings</h3>
        <dl class="clear">
          <dd class="selected">
            <div class="skin-section">
              <h4>Live</h4>
              <ul class="list">

                <li>
                  <input type="hidden" name="ckboxList[]" id="Ckbox1" value="0">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="ckboxList[]" id="Ckbox1" value="1">
                  <label for="Ckbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="hidden" name="ckboxList[]" id="Ckbox2" value="0">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="ckboxList[]" value="1" id="Ckbox2" checked>
                  <label for="Ckbox2">Checkbox 2</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="hidden" name="ckboxList[]" id="Ckbox3" value="0">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="ckboxList[]" value="1" id="Ckbox3" >
                  <label for="Ckbox3">Checkbox 3</label>
                </li>          

            </div>

            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.skin-polaris input').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_polaris',
                radioClass: 'iradio_polaris',
                increaseArea: '20%'
              });
            });
            </script>


          </dd>

        </dl>

          <input type="submit" class="list" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update Table">   

      </div>

    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is tableReduced.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding"/> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //go to checkbox web page
        function btn_changeColumns_onClick()
        {
            //it doesn't like localhost here
            window.location.href = "checkbox3.html"; 
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <p>
            <label>CheckboxList: It is Monday
                <?php
                    if (isset ($_POST["ckboxList"])) { 
                        $theFrm = implode(", ", $_POST["ckboxList"]);
                        echo $_POST[$theFrm];   
                    }
                 ?>
            </label>
        </p>
    </div>
<table id="tableone" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="col1">Header 1</th><th class="col2">Header 2</th><th class="col2">Header 3</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tr class="del">
        <td contenteditable="false">Row 0 Column 0</td>
        <td contenteditable="false">Row 0 Column 1</td>
        <td contenteditable="false">Row 0 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="del">
        <td contenteditable="false">Row 1 Column 0</td>
        <td contenteditable="false">Row 1 Column 1</td>
        <td contenteditable="false">Row 1 Column 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <input id="chgColumns" type="button" value="Change Columns Displayed"
           onclick="return btn_changeColumns_onClick()" />
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried using implode with the ckboxList[] but it's not giving me the labels that I want, it's giving me 0, 0, 1, 0. See pertinent code marked with **.

So my question is, how do I POST the entire form, or how do I POST the ckboxList[] and obtain the label names instead of 0/1.

Helpful links I've been looking at are:

[Beginner's Guide to HTML5 & CSS3 - Formidable Forms with HTML5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/761123/Beginners-Guide-to-HTML-CSS-Formidable-Forms-with)

[Beginner's Guide to HTML5 & CSS3 - Server Side Story](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769737/Beginners-Guide-to-HTML-CSS-Server-Side-Story)

http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-value-selected-checkboxes_cs

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes do not get transmitted during a post because they don't have any value. Folks have devised workarounds though - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542900/how-can-i-detect-unchecked-checkbox-with-php

Comment: So I tried adding "<input type="hidden" name="ckboxList[]" id="Ckbox2" value="0">" and now I'm getting 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 with the ckboxList [] back in, which is very very cool.  Any idea how I can get it to return the label names for the entire array too?  I need both.

Comment: Someone has solved that before too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415137/jquery-ajax-post-label-value-pair

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I took a stab at the AJAX part like the link you recommended above, but it's not showing the alert or any noticeable changes.  I'm not sure how to debug it.  Any suggestions?  I revised my code in my original question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle? It will likely be easier if we have the code that you're working with.

Comment: I've tried to do a JSFiddle, but they won't save with errors and I can't separate the JavaScript, HTML, etc well. Plus it's two files. I'll add the rest of table.php above and if you know how to do the JSFiddle that would help.

Comment: Can you reduce the issue to the minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem? Perhaps using a `console.log()` to output the data that should be sent to the PHP script? I don't know how much time I'll be able to spend on this today.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to reduce it and will have a change up in around 1/2 hour.

Comment: I reduced the code. I'm seeing a popup with the [{"Checkbox 1":"0",{"Checkbox 2":"0"},{"Checkbox 3":"0"}] and message with lala in it.  Console says ReferenceError: dataToServer is not defined.  I'm not sure why data is blank being sent over and not defined. HTML document check says Ckbox1 is being duplicated, along with the other id's in checkbox3.html. I thought I was doing what the link said to do with hidden.  Once I get the checkbox info in dataToServer, I'm not sure I'm receiving them ok or not in tableReduced.php.

Comment: dataToServer is not in scope when you try to use it because the AJAX function lies outside of your document ready handler.

Comment: Where do you think dataToServer belongs to be defined? I tried var dataToServer = [] above submit on click function, and also below that, and also below myCheckboxForm label each function.  None seemed to help.

Comment: Put your AJAX function inside of your document ready handler. I wish I had more visibility into your project.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - I updated the ajax part so they are both in same document ready function but now I'm not seeing alert messages in that area. See code above. If you have any ideas how to give you more visibility into the project, let me know.

Comment: Have you tried using [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/). It's how I send check boxes and radios with name and all. Instead of your long process of getting the name and values by hand, just set the ajax data to `var dataToServer = $('form').serializeArray()` and it will construct it into proper data sent to server. Also, implode is only going to give you the values. If you want the keys, look at something like [`array_keys`](http://us3.php.net/array_keys)

Comment: dataToServer is still not defined.

Comment: @SpYk3HH - that gave me what I needed.  Thanks!  Now I have to figure out how my post needs to be in table.php. I really appreciate it! I updated my code above.

Comment: I'm going to call the original question answered.  Thanks Guys!

Answer (score -1):

```
    If you want to post a form by clicking checkbox , then you can use a method like this
```

make two files, first is in html from where you want to post a php form
it is demo.html
make a form in html file and post it a php file 
like  del.php is a file where our form will post

```
   First File 
-Demo.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="del.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Check Box</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk-1" name="chk-1"/>Click Me</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="sub" value="" id="sub"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
<script>
    $("#chk-1").click(function() {
        $("#sub").click();

    });
</script>
-----------------------------------------------
second php file
-del.php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    var_dump($_POST);
}
?>

        If you don't wan to show a submit button then you can hide it,you can post form by jquery dom,by binding checkbox click event
```

Comment: I think the anwser should include a brief explanation, may be separated from the code.